# profile image of O365: best place to upload it or no difference?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, image

In all places where I had sharepoint on premise, the upload image in skype and outlook was disabled and the only entry point was SP, with that element mapped back to AD.

In the O365 (in a hybrid situation with cloud in sync to an AD on premise), there is no mapping of the image back to AD, therefore, is it still true that the best place to upload the personal image to have it replicated in skype and outlook is About me in SP or it is completely irrelevant and any starting point (outlook, skype or SP) is equally valid?

Comment: Even if you click on the change profile photo link in the about me section - it takes you to the my account section of the outlook web app where you can change the profile photo across O365 apps. For large number of users running Powershell against exchange online is the best option. http://www.geekshangout.com/office-365-changing-users-profile-picture/